# How to translate "mental jobs" to russian?

Tags: перевод

mental jobs - психическая работа ?

In russian, there are two labors: `Умственный труд` vs `Физический труд`

What I can compose is:

`mental jobs - рабочие места для умственного труда`

How it names right?

Comment: Sorry, no. There are plenty of offers in google with this sentences. I'm think that Alexander is correct.

Comment: Like "Apply online for mental jobs today", "11260 available Mental jobs found on example.com"?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: What is menatal job? Is it something the psi-corps do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that for the phrase "mental jobs" is the most suitable the follow - **умственная работа**.

Of course, the phrase translation depends on the context.
For example:

- "Я выполняю **умственную работу**" - is correct
- "Я занимаюсь умственным трудом" - is correct too
- "Я выполняю **умственный труд**" - is not correct

Comment: "я работник умственного труда" is ok too

Answer (score 1):

I think, `Интеллектуальная работа` can also be used in such context.